# Why is single-spa CLI for Angular not creating necessary files?

Tags: micro-frontend, single-spa, single-spa-angular

When I run the CLI to standup a React and Angular MFE in a single-spa ecosystem, the React app runs smoothly but I am not given an option to add routing for Angular nor does it create the necessary main.single-spa.ts. Is the CLI Broken and should I follow an alternative approach to implement the Angular MFE?

[image]

Comment: This should be opened as an issue in single-spa-angular. The generator in create-single-spa is pretty straightforward and all it does is invokes `ng add single-spa-angular` (https://github.com/single-spa/create-single-spa/blob/main/packages/generator-single-spa/src/angular/generator-single-spa-angular.js#L68). You'll be asked to provide a reproduction repo if you do. Contributors are needed so if you're interested/able, begin by looking at the ng-add schematic https://github.com/single-spa/single-spa-angular/tree/master/schematics/ng-add

Comment: The solution that I just found involved invoking those ng single-spa commands manually. I wonder whats going on in the generator. Thank you for your insight and Ill look into raising a ticket for everyones benefit.